# Quart: sync vs async parsing form data

Tags: python, file-upload, python-asyncio, multipartform-data, quart

I'm investigating the performance of uploading files to the `Quart` web server

I'm looking at how `Quart` parses file data when the request type is `"multipart/form-data"`, and I see that synchronous temporary files are used to write files to the stream

```
def default_stream_factory(
    total_content_length: int | None,
    content_type: str | None,
    filename: str | None,
    content_length: int | None = None,
) -> t.IO[bytes]:
    max_size = 1024 * 500

    if SpooledTemporaryFile is not None:
        return t.cast(t.IO[bytes], SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=max_size, mode="rb+"))
    elif total_content_length is None or total_content_length > max_size:
        return t.cast(t.IO[bytes], TemporaryFile("rb+"))

    return BytesIO()
```

I have a question: in the form parser (`quart.formparser.MultiPartParser`) is it intentionally made synchronous writing to the `container` (file data stream), instead of using asynchronous writing, for example with `aiofiles`?

I want to make sure that the really synchronous recording of multipart chunks is done intentionally

For *what reasons* is this done, would this work better under high load and multiple coroutines?

I tried implementing the `aiofiles` option and got a slight performance reduction (5-10%) with `wrk` tool and script:

```
function read_file(path)
    local file, errorMessage = io.open(path, "rb")
    if not file then
        error("Could not read the file:" .. errorMessage .. "\n")
    end
  
    local content = file:read "*all"
    file:close()
    return content
  end
  
  local Boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L"
  local BodyBoundary = "--" .. Boundary
  local LastBoundary = "--" .. Boundary .. "--"
  local CRLF = "\r\n"
  local FileBody = read_file("./text_file.txt")
  local Filename = "file"
  local ContentDisposition = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' .. Filename .. '"'
  local ContentType = 'Content-Type: text/plain'
  
  wrk.method = "POST"
  wrk.headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" .. Boundary
  wrk.headers["Transfer-Encoding"] = "chunked"
  wrk.body = BodyBoundary .. CRLF .. ContentDisposition .. CRLF .. ContentType .. CRLF .. CRLF .. FileBody .. CRLF .. LastBoundary
```

(note, I specified `wrk.headers["Transfer-Encoding"] = "chunked"`, which required me to build `wrk` with this PR - https://github.com/wg/wrk/pull/504)

with command:

```
wrk -t3 -c3 -d100s -s ufile.lua http://localhost:8000/
```

at a file size of **100 MB** the result is:

without `aiofiles` (native `quart.formparser.MultiPartParser`):

```
Running 2m test @ http://localhost:8000/
  3 threads and 3 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     1.62s    99.26ms   1.93s    70.65%
    Req/Sec     0.00      0.00     0.00    100.00%
  184 requests in 1.67m, 32.16KB read
Requests/sec:      1.84
Transfer/sec:     329.10B
```

with `aiofiles`:

```
Running 2m test @ http://localhost:8000/
  3 threads and 3 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     1.67s   116.26ms   2.00s    70.30%
    Req/Sec     0.00      0.00     0.00    100.00%
  176 requests in 1.67m, 30.77KB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 11
Requests/sec:      1.76
Transfer/sec:     314.79B
```

at a file size of **10 MB** the result is:
without `aiofiles` (native `quart.formparser.MultiPartParser`):

```
Running 2m test @ http://localhost:8000/
  3 threads and 3 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   173.16ms   38.79ms 503.89ms   81.60%
    Req/Sec     6.42      2.55    10.00     62.39%
  1739 requests in 1.67m, 303.99KB read
Requests/sec:     17.38
Transfer/sec:      3.04KB
```

with `aiofiles`:

```
Running 2m test @ http://localhost:8000/
  3 threads and 3 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   195.36ms   42.38ms 519.98ms   80.43%
    Req/Sec     5.49      2.16    10.00     71.86%
  1539 requests in 1.67m, 269.16KB read
Requests/sec:     15.38
Transfer/sec:      2.69KB
```

route is implemented like this

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
async def upload_file() -> str:
    await request.files
    return "uploaded"
```

the modified part of the parser looks like this

```
...
    if isinstance(event, Field):
        current_part = event
        container = []
        _write = run_sync(container.append)
    elif isinstance(event, File):
        current_part = event
        container: AsyncBufferedReader = await self.start_file_streaming(event, content_length)
        _write = container.write
    elif isinstance(event, Data):
        await _write(event.data)
...
```

If my tests are correct, I'd like to understand why this happens and if there are any useful ways to use `aiofiles` when parsing form data?